# Why are posterior predictions "jagged"?

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm trying to understand how to include group-level effects in posterior predictions. I am reproducing a figure from Statistical Rethinking by Richard McElreath, but using the R packages `brms` and `tidybayes` to do the work. A fully reproducible example is below (requires several packages)

My understanding is that by setting `re_formula = NULL`, the uncertainty in the random effects is propagated into the predicted values (Note that this is an argument to `tidybayes::add_predicted_samples`, which wraps `brms::posterior_predict`). I thought that the way this happens is to sample a new observation (cultures in this example) from the possible population of cultures, for every new predicted value.

However, in the text the figure is shown with a smooth line and smooth intervals, while my examples are always very jagged. They seem to get more jagged the more simulated x-values I try to include. Why is this?

```r
library(brms)
#> Loading required package: Rcpp
#> Warning: package 'Rcpp' was built under R version 3.4.3
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading 'brms' package (version 2.1.3). Useful instructions
#> can be found by typing help('brms'). A more detailed introduction
#> to the package is available through vignette('brms_overview').
#> Run theme_set(theme_default()) to use the default bayesplot theme.
library(tidybayes)
library(tidyverse)
#> Loading tidyverse: tibble
#> Loading tidyverse: tidyr
#> Loading tidyverse: readr
#> Loading tidyverse: purrr
#> Loading tidyverse: dplyr
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.4.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.4.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.2
#> Conflicts with tidy packages ----------------------------------------------
#> filter(): dplyr, stats
#> lag():    dplyr, stats
library(modelr)
library(ggplot2)

data("Kline", package = "rethinking")

Kline$logpop <- log(Kline$population)

tools_pop_bf <- bf(total_tools ~ 0 + intercept + logpop + (1|culture), family = "poisson")

priors <- c(set_prior("normal(0, 1)", class = "b", coef = "logpop"),
            set_prior("normal(0, 10)", class = "b", coef = "intercept"),
            set_prior("cauchy(0, 1)", class = "sd"))

tools_pop_brms <- brm(tools_pop_bf, data = Kline, prior = priors, chains = 1, cores =1)
#> Compiling the C++ model
#> Start sampling
#> 
#> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'poisson brms-model' NOW (CHAIN 1).
#> 
#> Gradient evaluation took 4.6e-05 seconds
#> 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.46 seconds.
#> Adjust your expectations accordingly!
#> 
#> 
#> Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
#> Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
#> Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
#> Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
#> Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
#> Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
#> Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
#> Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
#> Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
#> Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
#> Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
#> Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
#> 
#>  Elapsed Time: 0.752364 seconds (Warm-up)
#>                0.613657 seconds (Sampling)
#>                1.36602 seconds (Total)

post_samp <- Kline %>% 
  data_grid(logpop = seq_range(logpop, n = 200)) %>% 
  add_predicted_samples(model = tools_pop_brms, re_formula = NULL, allow_new_levels = TRUE)

inters <- post_samp %>% 
  median_hdi(.prob = c(0.73, 0.89, 0.97))

inters %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(prob_fac = factor(.prob),
         prob_fac = forcats::fct_reorder(prob_fac, .prob, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = logpop, y = pred)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = prob_fac)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens", direction = -1) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(12, 70)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: For posterity, it looks like you can get a smooth line using: add_fitted_samples(model = tools_pop_brms, re_formula = NULL, allow_new_levels = TRUE) and ggplot(aes(x = logpop, y = estimate)) credit: @ucfagls